# data frame into numeric categories

Tags: r

I have a data and its `dput` is given below.

**Data:**

```
dput(data)
structure(c(12L, 2L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 12L), .Label = c("0 Ã  10 cm", 
"10 Ã  20 cm", "100 Ã  110 cm", "110 Ã  120 cm", "120 Ã  130 cm", 
"130 Ã  140 cm", "140 Ã  150 cm", "150 Ã  160 cm", "160 Ã  170 cm", 
"170 Ã  180 cm", "180 Ã  190 cm", "20 Ã  30 cm", "30 Ã  40 cm", 
"40 Ã  50 cm", "50 Ã  60 cm", "60 Ã  70 cm", "70 Ã  80 cm", "80 Ã  90 cm", 
"90 Ã  100 cm", "N/A"), class = "factor")
```

The data is french, basically, it is categories from 0 to 10, from 10 to 20 and so on.  I need to replace the second column with numbers, for example,  0 Ã  10 cm  I need to assign to 1,  10  Ã  20 cm - to 2 and so on, how can I  automatically replace values with the number based on the category in R?

In the new table, I need to get column 2 replacing the `A` with the category levels and the column 2 will have values as given below.:

```
2 1 4 1 1 2 4 3 4 2
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand your data structure. Please provide an example dataset.

Comment: I need to assign the number based on text for example from 0 to 10 it should be 1, from 20 to 30 - should be 2 and so on

Comment: `as.numeric(as.factor())` ought to do.

Comment: Please have a look at [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061). Your goal is clear. But there is a problem that we don't know how your data look - is it a vector? a data frame? Some other structure? What class is it? Is it in one column or multiple columns? We can see that Sathish assumes you have 4 columns, but your comment to the answer suggests you have just 1 column. These questions can be answered if you follow the [reproducible example advice here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to tidy your data to clean structure. I did it in the data section. Then convert column one to factor and then to numeric, to get the category levels, and assign it to column 2.

```
df[, 2] <- as.numeric( factor( df[[1]]) )

#    X1 X2    X3
# 1  20  2 30 cm
# 2  10  1 20 cm
# 3  40  4 50 cm
# 4  10  1 20 cm
# 5  10  1 20 cm
# 6  20  2 30 cm
# 7  40  4 50 cm
# 8  30  3 40 cm
# 9  40  4 50 cm
# 10 20  2 30 cm
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(c(12L, 2L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 12L),
                .Label = c("0 Ã  10 cm", "10 Ã  20 cm", "100 Ã  110 cm", "110 Ã  120 cm", "120 Ã  130 cm", 
                           "130 Ã  140 cm", "140 Ã  150 cm", "150 Ã  160 cm", "160 Ã  170 cm", 
                           "170 Ã  180 cm", "180 Ã  190 cm", "20 Ã  30 cm", "30 Ã  40 cm", 
                           "40 Ã  50 cm", "50 Ã  60 cm", "60 Ã  70 cm", "70 Ã  80 cm", "80 Ã  90 cm", 
                           "90 Ã  100 cm", "N/A"), class = "factor")
```

**Tidy your data:**

```
df <- as.character( df )  # convert factor to character
df <- data.frame( do.call('rbind', strsplit( df, "\ ") ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE )  # split string by spaces and row bind them together
df$X3 <- paste( df$X4, df$X5, sep = ' ')   # combine column 4 & 5 together and assign it to column 3
df[, c('X4', 'X5')] <- NULL  # remove column 4 and 5
df$X1 <- as.numeric( df$X1)  # convert column 1 to numeric
df                           # structure of data 
#    X1 X2    X3
# 1  20  Ã 30 cm
# 2  10  Ã 20 cm
# 3  40  Ã 50 cm
# 4  10  Ã 20 cm
# 5  10  Ã 20 cm
# 6  20  Ã 30 cm
# 7  40  Ã 50 cm
# 8  30  Ã 40 cm
# 9  40  Ã 50 cm
# 10 20  Ã 30 cm
```

Comment: this might work, and one more question - how can I spread the data into (0  Ã  10 cm) into V1 V2 V3 and so on?

Comment: Thank you, Sathish! I will try it now!

Comment: @L.Bond `cut` command is the right one for this task, so I removed the previous two approaches.

Comment: Thank you! But I still have a problem - all the values "0  Ã  10 cm" is in the one column, is there a way to break in into different colums?

Comment: please use this command `dput(data)` and post the output of it in your question. It will help people to understand the structure of your data. Please see Gregor's comment on reproducible example.

Comment: > dput(c)
structure(c(12L, 2L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 12L), .Label = c("0 Ã  10 cm", 
"10 Ã  20 cm", "100 Ã  110 cm", "110 Ã  120 cm", "120 Ã  130 cm", 
"130 Ã  140 cm", "140 Ã  150 cm", "150 Ã  160 cm", "160 Ã  170 cm", 
"170 Ã  180 cm", "180 Ã  190 cm", "20 Ã  30 cm", "30 Ã  40 cm", 
"40 Ã  50 cm", "50 Ã  60 cm", "60 Ã  70 cm", "70 Ã  80 cm", "80 Ã  90 cm", 
"90 Ã  100 cm", "N/A"), class = "factor")

Comment: I beg my pardon the question was not clear